# php session will not update with ajax uploader

Tags: php, ajax, session, cookies, upload

i having an issue in php script and ajax uploader
in my index.php have this similar script:

```
'onUploadComplete':function(file,response) { $('body').append('+response+'<br/>Delete code: <?php echo $_SESSION['deletetoken'];$_SESSION['deletetoken'] = '?';unset($_SESSION['deletetoken']);session_unset(); ?>')}
```

may not exactly correct,and the session already started inside `<head></head>` php script

and my upload.php script:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($temp,$locate)){
$_SESSION['deletetoken'] = substr(md5('swvybkl.signature/481651561.55r'),5,6);
echo $url;
}
```

but when I upload more than one file will echo

> http://xx.xx/abc.jpg
>
> Delete code: example
>
> http://xx.xx/123.jpg
>
> Delete code: example

problem is the delete code is same,how to fouce update it only using php without javascript/mysql?

Comment: Are you wanting to output a json array with delete codes?

Comment: no just print the delete code for each upload

Comment: Is `substr(md5('swvybkl.signature/481651561.55r'),5,6)` a static string or is it made from a dynamic variable? Otherwise it will always return the same code.

Comment: it's dynamic variable,this example i changed it to static string,original is substr() from the file url

Comment: Are the delete codes loaded from a single PHP page or jQuery? If php, do you need to use Sessions at all? Also, if single PHP page does the `session_unset()` act as session_destroy needing another `session_start()` to be called?